# Showing Validation Error for SetValue - ReactNative Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am Using `ReactNative TypeScript` for `Dropdown` picker. I am facing a Type Error for the
`SetValue`, tried with string and array of objects, but still the same. Why is this? I have
tried to find the solution for this, but unfortunately couldn't able to find it.
Attaching the screenshot for the ref.

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-G7U_1w_qNuo/YLSNPggvHyI/AAAAAAAAD8Q/G7xWahwqmXci0FKz8QvyaHxYwDb7GOkZACJEEGAsYHg/s0/2021-05-31.png?authuser=0

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-PcZGXJEjYQY/YLSNSzoJEZI/AAAAAAAAD8U/rmQdd_eLYeoiuK_P2ur9dbSGBWrJaiH4gCJEEGAsYHg/s0/2021-05-31.png?authuser=0

DropDown Library - https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker

`setValue={(val: string) => setValue(val)}`

State:
`const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");`

```
<DropDownPicker
                        style={subscriptionOrderStyles.countryContainer}
                        dropDownContainerStyle={subscriptionOrderStyles.dropDownContainer}
                        placeholderStyle={subscriptionOrderStyles.countryPlaceHolder}
                        textStyle={subscriptionOrderStyles.dropDownTextStyle}
                        placeholder="Country"
                        dropDownDirection="AUTO"
                        showTickIcon={false}
                        showArrowIcon={true}
                        ArrowDownIconComponent={() => (
                            <Image
                                source={require("../assets/Vectordropdown.png")}
                                style={subscriptionOrderStyles.arrowIconStyles}
                            />
                        )}
                        ArrowUpIconComponent={() => (
                            <Image
                                source={require("../assets/Vectordropdown.png")}
                                style={subscriptionOrderStyles.arrowIconStyles}
                            />
                        )}
                        open={open}
                        value={value}
                        items={items}
                        setOpen={setOpen}
                        setValue={(val: string) => setValue(val)}
                        setItems={setItems}
                    />
```

Comment: You did not attach a screenshot.

Comment: Can you please share more code?

Comment: Attached Screenshot and code over on the Description.